# How to properly keep config files in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I've built a piece of software which uses Laravel config module to consume certain settings.

Thing is, we're using Laravel Forge to auto-deploy, and everytime we deploy, configs are reset to the "blank" state, thus breaking some things everytime I deploy.

I have added the files to .gitignore, but doesn't seem to do the trick.

Can anyone point me towards the right direction in order to save this config files without having the re-set them everyime we deploy?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Which config files are you talking about ? are you using the .env file  ?

Comment: No, I'm using .php files, under config directory, thing is the software as a setting editor which writes the file. The problem is, those modified settings are reset on each auto deploy.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to have an example of your config and .env files

Config files for multiple environments rely on `.env` files in each environment.

[`env()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L565) returns either the matching variable from your .env or the value specified.

so `env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sqs')` would look into the `.env` file for the `QUEUE_DRIVER` variable if it can't find a variable it returns the default `'sqs'`.

An example of a queue config file might looks like this.

**config/queue.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sqs'),
      'connections' => [  
        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],
        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' =>  env('SQS_KEY'),
            'secret' =>  env('SQS_SECRET'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_URL'),
            'queue' => 'general_queue',
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
        ],
      ],
    ];
```

You would then set your variables in your .env file for each environment.

Production may look like this.

**.env**

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sqs

SQS_KEY=yoursqskey
SQS_SECRET=yoursqssecret
SQS_URL=yoursqsurl
```

Your local environment might look like this.

**.env**

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

You can edit your `.env` file in forge under Sites > Site Details > Environment

Comment: Thing is we're using a web interface to edit the settings, right? So the config is then saved under the **config** directory, under the same file. PRoblem is every time we auto-deploy, the configs are reset, thus the files being in gitignore

Comment: You shouldn't have environmental variables in your config files. What you do is commit your configs to your repo and you add the `.env` files to you `.gitignore` otherwise you have to problems you are facing. If you post your config files I can give you some more guidance.